# Regex, check number between specific range of lengths. C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, range

I have the following regex to check if a number with 11 digits are entered

```
^[0-9]{11}$
```

Now I instead want to check if the number has 11-14 digits, how should I change my regex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `{}` can take 2 arguments {min,max}

```
^[0-9]{11,14}$
```